# How to add context menu to Silverlight tree items?

Tags: c#, silverlight, menu, tree, contextmenu

I want to have context menus attached to tree items in my Silverlight Toolkit tree. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click support is only supported via Javascript, so the vendor route is a good way to go.

Curtisk's suggestion of the Telerik control is a good choice, but this can be tricky to implement first time - if you go this route make sure you pay a few extra pounds for their support - the documentation is lousy.

Have you considered any alternatives to context menus? At the moment I am working on project porting a thick client application to Silverlight. We had a lot of right click context in the thick app, and after consulting with Microsoft's UX team and also looking at the examples on [Quince UX](http://quince.infragistics.com/) we decided to implement our context menus in a permanent task based menu on the right hand side of our screen. Implementation is a doodle with binding and, most importantly, our users have received this well :-)

Answer (score 1):

One way is vendor provided.....

Telerik has RADControls for Silverlight, the contextmenu control can be attached to tree views.

http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight.aspx

and

http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight/contextmenu.aspx

for more details and demo with tree

Comment: Ahhh! The challenge at hand! I like your style!